# batch requests answer but can't automate it?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to copy a file and the cmd returns asking if C:\test\2006 is indicating a file name or a folder name at its location

(B= file, D= folder)?

I know that I want D = folder however I can't seem to autorun this

for those able to read Dutch this is the code it returns:

```
Geeft C:\test\2006 een bestandsnaam of een mapnaam op het doel aan
(B = bestand, D = map)?
```

Comment: oh nvm, you are doing this in dos :P

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `\` to the end of the path to indicate that it's a folder:

```
copy whatever C:\test\2006\
```

---

To answer the question, you need to pipe a character to standard in:

```
echo d | copy whatever C:\test\2006
```

Comment: +1, that is the solution if he *cannot* change the source code of the program

Answer (score 1):

Are you using XCOPY? If so, use the `/I` option.

Comment: +1, that is the solution if he can change the source code of the program.